# What does this regex for @mentions do?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I've been trying to figure out what this regex mean - and I'm not getting very far.

```
(\w+\.?(?:\w+)?)
```

The language is Javascript.

I understand parts of this regex - it looks like it's capturing dots, any word, but forbidding word.word - but I'm not sure?

Comment: `\w` is word.  `\.` is a just a period.  `?` means 0 or one of the previous item.  (may be a group `()`)  - Read regex.info quick start: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html  For `(?:)?` in Grouping and Capturing section.

Comment: At least one word character followed by an optional dot followed by optional word characters.

Comment: Where did you get that from? It doesn't make much sense, and could be easily simplified to `\w+\.?\w*`. Probably the author wanted `\w+(?:\.\w+)?`

Comment: I'm with @Bergi; the optional `\w+` after the optional `\.` is sort of confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It's not forbidding `word.word`. The `(?:…)` creates a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). It's just like a regular `(…)` group, but it is not extracted in a separate capture in the result.

So, this is equivalent to `(\w+\.?(\w+)?)`, except that it only has 1 capture group.

Answer (score 1):

It's matching a word (letters, numbers, underscore), optionally followed by a dot, optionally followed by another word. Like:

```
"foo"
"foo."
"foo.bar"
```

Breakdown:

- `\w+` a word (as you already knew)
- `\.?` an optional dot. The `?` means "match zero or one of these"
- `(?:\w+)?` an optional word. The `?:` at the beginning means "don't capture this" (as opposed to the parens enclosing the whole thing, which mean "*do* capture this); and the `?` at the end means, again, that it's optional

Comment: No. I gave that as an example that it will match. Nothing is being "forbidden" in the regex.

Comment: sorry, what I meant was this. If I had foo.bar. and I only wanted to capture foo.bar then what would I do?

Comment: @praks5432 If given an input string, `"foo.bar."`, this regex will only capture `"foo.bar"`. Test it yourself: `"foo.bar.".match(/(\w+\.?(?:\w+)?)/)`

Comment: @praks5432: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. Yes, given the string `"foo.bar."` (with a trailing dot), this pattern will only match the initial `"foo.bar"`.